# no puedo insertar datos en mi bbdd a partir de un excel

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, csv

Hoola, muy buenas, básicamente quiero introducir datos de un excel en una tabla de mi base de datos que la tengo en mi phpMyAdmin.

Esta es mi vista:

**hola.html:**

```
<html>
 <head>    
 </head>
 <body>
   <form action="hola.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div>
    <label>Import CSV File:</label>
    <input type="file"  name="csv" id="csv">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 <body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**hola.php:**

```
<?php
require('config/connect.php');


$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

$time = date("d/m/Y"); # Fecha Actual

$disponible = 'disponible';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE){

        $sql = "INSERT into doc_documents values($data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4], $data[5], '$descripcio','$time')";

        //var_dump($data);
        //echo $data[0];

        //$sql = "INSERT into doc_documents (num_box, empresa, num_expedientes, tipus_document, num_expedient, descripcio, estado, fecha_entrada)
                //values('".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."', '".$data[3]."', '".$data[4]."', '".$data[5]."', '".$disponible."', '".$time."')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    }
}
```

Esta es mi tabla de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo el contenido de mi excel (los demás campos los autocompleta mi programa, no hace falta introducirlos con el excel):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle a "upload" después de haber subido el excel e impreso la primera posición del array `$data`, me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa es que yo soy consciente de que si hago `$data[0]` me pillará toda la fila (captura de arriba), entonces, ¿cómo puedo acceder a cada posición que se separa entre punto y coma (;) de cada posición del array que cojo el excel?

Un saludo y perdonad la molestias, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes usar `explode` o bien, si es un `.csv` usar la función propia de PHP para leer csv: [**`fgetcsv()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: Tienes una linea comentada ¿Porque no has intentado con esa? no estas definiendo los campos solo los valores

Comment: Actualmente ya estoy utilizando la función ```fgetcsv()``` en el ```while``` de la línea 14 de mi fichero ```hola.php```.

Comment: La línea que está comentada ya la he utilizado pero no funciona bien, no me inserta los datos, por eso la comenté, jejeje.